# Memory optimisation

Tags: matlab, memory-optimization

I'm just curious to know if I can reduce memory usage of Matlab by using some option.
Clicking on a variable in workspace shows a long digit which may not be necessary in most of cases. e.g.,

```
[20, 25.0540913632159, 16.2750000000000, 3.08852992798468];
```

for me `25.054091` may be more than ok. Are there any options that Matlab just reduce numbers for internal calculation and does it make any difference.

Comment: maybe this one can partially answer your question; http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/47142 (Don't forget to ask yourself if this "memory optimisation" is really worth it)

Comment: These days, most PCs have so much RAM in them that they allow you the luxury of not having to care about wasting a few bits here and there. As you will find out soon if you continue along this route, this really is a luxury worth having, because *having* to care can be a real pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern PC's use *floating point numbers* to calculate non-integral values.

These come in two standardized variants: `float` and `double`, where the latter is twice the size of the former.

Matlab, by default uses (complex) `double`s for all its calculations.

You can force it to use `float` (or as Matlab calls them, `single`) by specifiying the type:

```
a = single([20, 25.0540913632159, 16.2750000000000, 3.08852992798468]);
```

This should use half the memory, and you lose some precision that may or may not be important in your application. Make sure the optimization is worth it before doing this, as execution speed may even be slower (due to builtin functions only operating on `double`, hence requiring two conversions extra).

Comment: Since Matlab refers to `float` as `single` the conversion should be `a = single([ numbers here ]);`